# How to resolve Syntax error (missing operator) error while using the Access as db for C# Windows application?

Tags: ms-access

Error :-

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId'
```

Used script :-

```
string sql = "select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate," +
    "PriceHistory.DateAssigned, PriceHistory.DateChanged, PriceHistory.MRP, PriceHistory.ProductOffer " +
     "from ProductPrice " +
     "inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId " +
     "inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId";
     "left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Products.SupplierId ";
     " where Products.ProductCode='" + productCode + "'";
```

Comment: First of all, you have a couple of `;` where you need `+` -- I assume you mis-copied your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. my query changed as follows,but still i am getting same error :(

Comment: Script :- "select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate," +
                            "PriceHistory.DateAssigned,PriceHistory.DateChanged,PriceHistory.MRP,PriceHistory.ProductOffer " +
                            "from ProductPrice " +
                            "inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId " +
                            "inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId"+ 
                            "left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Products.SupplierId "+ 
                            " where Products.ProductCode='" + productCode + "'";

Answer (score 1):

You need a space before the end of your quotes

```
string sql = "select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate," + 
"PriceHistory.DateAssigned, PriceHistory.DateChanged, PriceHistory.MRP, PriceHistory.ProductOffer " + 
 "from ProductPrice " + 
 "inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId " + 
 "inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId " + 
 "left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Products.SupplierId " +
 " where Products.ProductCode='" + productCode + "'";
```

Comment: string sql = "select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate," +                            "PriceHistory.DateAssigned,PriceHistory.DateChanged,PriceHistory.MRP,PriceHistory.ProductOffer " +
"from ProductPrice " +
                            "inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId " +
                            "inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID = ProductPrice.PrdcId " + 
                            "left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Products.SupplierId " + 
                            " where Products.ProductCode= '" + productCode + "'";

Comment: Still getting the same error.                                                select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate,PriceHistory.DateAssigned,PriceHistory.DateChanged,PriceHistory.MRP,PriceHistory.ProductOffer from ProductPrice inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID = ProductPrice.PrdcId left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Prdc.SupplierId where Prdc.ProductCode = 'df'

Comment: Here, make your life easy by wriling long sql strings like this:                string sql = @"select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate, PriceHistory.DateAssigned, 
                PriceHistory.DateChanged, PriceHistory.MRP, PriceHistory.ProductOffer 
                from ProductPrice 
                inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId 
                inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId 
                left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Products.SupplierId 
                where Products.ProductCode = '"+ productCode + "'";

Comment: Why are you joining to supplier and product price if all the fields you are selecting are from the pricehistory table? Surely you can do this: SELECT PH.UnitSellRate, PH.DateAssigned, PH.DateChanged, PH.MRP, PH.ProductOffer from PriceHistory AS PH inner join Prdc AS P on P.prdcID = PH.PrdcId where P.ProductCode = 'df'

Comment: Script :- select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate,
PriceHistory.DateAssigned,
PriceHistory.DateChanged,
PriceHistory.MRP,
PriceHistory.ProductOffer,
Suppliers.SupplierName
                                  from ProductPrice 
                                  inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId 
                                  inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID = ProductPrice.PrdcId 
                                  left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Prdc.SupplierId 
                                  where Prdc.ProductCode = '" + productCode + "'";

Comment: suppliers has been used to get the supplier name

Comment: there is join with prdc table.

Comment: Ah, this is access.... ugh :) http://snipplr.com/view/18926/ms-access-sql-join-syntax-for-3way-table-join/

Comment: @"select PriceHistory.UnitSellRate, PriceHistory.DateAssigned, 
                    PriceHistory.DateChanged, PriceHistory.MRP, PriceHistory.ProductOffer, 
                    Suppliers.SupplierName from ((ProductPrice 
                    inner join PriceHistory on PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId) 
                    inner join Prdc on prdc.prdcID = ProductPrice.PrdcId) 
                    left join Suppliers on Suppliers.supplierId = Prdc.SupplierId 
                    where Prdc.ProductCode = '" + productCode + "'";

Comment: Im new to MsAccess Can u give me any url to refer furtherly.. As because the syntax that im using is of sql server is not working at here

Comment: I avoid access at all cost, but I suppose msdn would be the place to go

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two main problems that I can see (other than the spacing and semicolon problems already identified):

1 - Access/Jet requires parentheses when performing more than one join. Basically, you need to essentially make up subqueries to ensure you're only joining two tables at a time, so instead of this:

```
SELECT 
        PriceHistory.UnitSellRate,
        PriceHistory.DateAssigned, 
        PriceHistory.DateChanged, 
        PriceHistory.MRP, 
        PriceHistory.ProductOffer
FROM
        ProductPrice
           INNER JOIN PriceHistory 
           ON PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId

           INNER JOIN Prdc
           ON prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId
```

...you need to wrap those inner joins in parentheses to create join two tables into one, that will then be joined to one more, etc, like this:

```
 SELECT 
    PriceHistory.UnitSellRate,
    PriceHistory.DateAssigned, 
    PriceHistory.DateChanged, 
    PriceHistory.MRP, 
    PriceHistory.ProductOffer
 FROM
 (ProductPrice INNER JOIN PriceHistory 
              ON PriceHistory.UnitPriceId = ProductPrice.UnitPriceId)
 INNER JOIN Prdc 
 ON prdc.prdcID=ProductPrice.PrdcId
```

2 - I'm not really sure what you're joining at the end with your LEFT JOIN. That LEFT JOIN is trying to join the `Suppliers` and `Products` tables, but neither of them seem to have any connection to anything in the INNER JOINs you've already made. Is it possible that Prdc and Products are the same table?

Comment: Was having this same issue, and wrapping the table and first inner join in parenthases worked for me!